# JavaScript Regex unexpected behavior with .test()

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating a Regular Expression in JavaScript which should look for both numbers (at least 1) and letters (at least 1), with the total length being between 6 and 10. I came across some unexpected behavior.

My regex - `/^[a-z+\d+]{6,10}$/g`.

This doesn't work properly because being in a character class, it checks for letters or numbers, but noth BOTH. Therefore, I would expect `"123456"` to fail, because while it contains 6 characters, and has at least 1 digit, it does not include 1 letter.

However, in the below code snippet, when I store the regex in the `rgx` variable and use `.test()` on it, it somehow correctly returns `false`, as shown in the second `console.log` statement. But on the very next line when I directly use the regex with `.test()`, it returns `true`.

```js
let rgx = /^[a-z+\d+]{6,10}$/g;

// works fine
console.log(rgx.test("abcd12"));

// returns false
console.log(rgx.test("123456"));

// same regex returns true
console.log(/^[a-z+\d+]{6,10}$/g.test("123456"));
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Unrelated, but `+` in you character class means “allow the + character”, not “one or more of the preceding”.

Comment: Try to execute the `test()` function twice with the same regex object and the same testing string: It won't return the same boolean. And here is why: https://siderite.blogspot.com/2011/11/careful-when-reusing-javascript-regexp.html

Comment: Have you tried reducing it to more simple parts? For example, what happens with a regex of just `^/[\d]$/g, and `rgx.test("1")`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
let rgx = /^[a-z+\d+]{6,10}$/g;
let rgx2 = /^[a-z+\d+]{6,10}$/g;
console.log(rgx.test("abcd12")); //true
console.log(rgx2.test("123456")); //true
```

It's because

> Javascript RegExp object is stateful i.e. if you re-use a RegExp object (with 'g' flag set), subsequent matches would start from the end of the last match.

Answer (score -1):

try this instead /^[^a-z0-9]{6,10}$/g

Comment: let regex = /^[a-z0-9]{6,10}$/g;
let regex2 = /^[a-z0-9]{6,10}$/g;
console.log(regex.test("abcd09")); //true
console.log(regex2.test("123456")); //true

Comment: The regex of the OP was not the problem, but rather the reuse of the regex for 2 test operations.